# Is it possible to generate a random double in Java without any pre-defined boundaries?

Tags: java, random, casting, integer, double

I read about [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) and [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and went through almost every post regarding generating random number on stack overflow.

I still can't figure out how to generate a random number without a per-defined boundaries.

I mean, I know it's possible to write

```
Random random = new Random();
int mynumber = random.nextInt(max-min) + min;
```

but what if I don't want to supply these `max` and `min`?
what if I want it to be also generated?

Bottom line, my purpose is to generate a random number, which can be also negative in the range of `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

I tried several ways:

```
 int max = (int)Math.random();
 int min = (int)Math.random();
 double myNumber = new Random().nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

does not work because `(int)Math.random()` always gets rounded to 0.

I also tried:

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double myNumber = new Random().nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

and I get `The call to 'nextInt' always fails as index is out of bounds` .

My purpose is to generate a random `double`, but `Random ().nextInt(x,y)` gets only **int** as `x and y`. and to do that **without** supplying pre-defined values of `max and min`.

How would you suggest me to do that?
To generate a random and different double at each run of the program?

Comment: If you're just asking about the API, `Random.nextInt()` will generate a 32 bit random integer.  If you mean "how would I implement this myself," that's a much longer answer.

Comment: @Andy how would you recommend to avoid using `ThreadLocalRandom` because it is quite dangerous to use for these type of things, which not necessarily need that (because there is no need for parallelism here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) without arguments.

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 2<sup>32</sup> possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

```
int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
```

Comment: What about `double`? Should I just upcast the received int from `Random#nextInt`? What about negative numbers? Is there any way to generate a number from the all possible values including negative ones? Because I did think about a sort of solution, and its to generate 2 different positives and subtract one from the the other and it might be negative afterwards. But is there a way to do that without it?

Comment: I'm not a fan of `ThreadLocal` and friends.  Like the Singleton pattern, it's quite dangerous in the hands of the unwary.  The docs of `ThreadLocalRandom` says this: *"Use of ThreadLocalRandom is particularly appropriate when multiple tasks (for example, each a ForkJoinTask) use random numbers in parallel in thread pools."*  So this is not really a general purpose random generator, it's for use only when you expect parallelism.  Sprinkling it around where it's not needed might be an anti-pattern.

Comment: @NoobCoder `Random#nextInt` can generate negative numbers. See the documentation that I quoted in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Unmitigated. and a follow up question based on what @markspace said, how would you recommend to avoid using `ThreadLocalRandom` because as already said, it is quite dangerous to use for these type of things, which not necessarily need that.

Comment: @NoobCoder You can directly initialize a `Random` once and use that each time.

Answer (score 4):

```
Double.longBitsToDouble(new Random().nextLong())
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning this can produce `NaN` and positive and negative infinities.  However, these are in fact valid `double` values.